# Enable an explicit button in ssrs to export to pdf and attach it to email

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have created an rdl file and I have hosted it in our client ssrs server. After running it I am getting 'export to' button, refresh button etc. But I need a button that exports the report to pdf and attaches it to mail and send it a specific email id.
Is there any way to configure ssrs to bring such a button explicitly in the report window?
And I am building the reports using MS SQL 2008 R2 report builder 3.0.
Help me ASAP
Thanks
Avinaash

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Report Manager - there is no way to simply "configure" a button to do the action you're wanting.  You could certainly hack such a button into the page, but that's probably a terrible idea.

If this doesn't need to be truly on-demand (as in, a button), perhaps a Subscription could work?  A Data Driven subscription would allow you to perform any logical checks necessary to know if an email needs to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Please reffer the following links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/464518/When-we-click-on-a-button-SEND-EMAIL-with-SSRS-rep

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd5d3830-c80a-489d-9a4c-ac9ca680751c/sending-custom-report-as-email?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please just don't add some links to answer the question. Try to explain. :)